# Hiding entities, and figuring out a bug in videosphere

Tags: aframe

I'm making a little art project using aframe. The functionality is pretty simple, there is a videosphere and four buttons. The project opens with the videosphere playing the title sequence, and all four buttons visible. Ideally, when someone clicks one of the three "Here" buttons, the video switches out to a different source, and the three "Here" buttons disappear. When the video finishes, or the "Home" button is pressed, the video should switch back to the title and the three "Here" buttons should reappear.

Right now the video switching out is not working exactly, as when multiple buttons are pressed each video plays concurrently instead of ending one to begin the other. Additionally, I don't know how to hide the buttons because I do not know much about programming.

https://glitch.com/~agreeable-rooster

here is the glitch where i am testing the project out.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will double check to see if video pauses when switching out `src` later. For now, you can try to manually pause the previous video (`videoEl.pause()`) until playing the next.